# RubyMine's built-in console runs out of space. How to wrap lines?

Tags: ruby, console, command, rubymine, word-wrap

When I'm using the built-in console in RubyMine, if the commands I type exceed a certain amount of characters the console will cease to display new characters.

I've looked through all the RubyMine settings for a 'wrap' option for the console but I don't seem to be able to find one.

Please help if you know where such an option is located. It's rather annoying not to be able to see half of a long command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the IRB console to use soft wraps or not. When the console window is the active window, either

- click the button with a picture of three sliders

or

- go to Help -> Find Action.
- enter "use soft wraps"
- hit return

to toggle soft wrapping between off and on.

(In general, you can sometimes find RubyMine functionality that you wish existed by searching in the search box in the upper left of the Preferences dialog. I found "Use Soft Wraps" (which I didn't know existed until just now) by searching for "wrap".)

Unfortunately, in my hands, this setting doesn't affect the Terminal window, which always wraps for me -- maybe that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Strangely enough this option seems to do nothing to effect the console. I turned it on and off to no avail.

Comment: I am still limited to 52 characters before they start to disappear.

Comment: Is it the Terminal window that you're trying to get to wrap? (I revised my answer, but I don't know what's up with Terminal.) What OS and shell are you using? If you're using something Unixy, what's TERM set to?

Comment: It was indeed the terminal window that is included as a plugin to RubyMine, which, since I am working on the beast called windows, calss up cmd.exe. It seems to be behaving now, it seems to depend on which window mode the terminal window has in RubyMine (Docked vs. Floating vs. pinned etc.) in docked mode it still exhibits the same behavior but when in floating mode it will wrap.